# How to fix Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0 android studio

Tags: java, android

i just joined android studio code java, however i am having a bit of difficulty: Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

I have consulted some workarounds like :gradle build --warning-mode=all . however I don't know where the following code is located? i tried using CMD and powershell but to no avail! what should i do to fix the above error.

Comment: What Android Studio version are you using? And can you add your gradle files.

Comment: What you get are warnings not errors. Unless you update to gradle 8 (which has not yet been released) you can ignore these warnings. And if gradle8 is release you can upgrade to v8 and then seen what is broken.